# Can you add HideInInspectorAttribute to multiple variables at once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have got the following code snippet

```
[HideInInspector]
public Color color;
[HideInInspector]
public bool active;
[HideInInspector]
public bool started;
[HideInInspector]
public PlayerAbilities playerAbilities;
[HideInInspector]
public PlayerMovement playerMovement;
[HideInInspector]
public PlayerControls controls;
```

And I really want to clean up this mess. 
All of the Variables need to be public, but i dont want them in the inspector. Is there a simple way to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make them into a property, that's the C# way anyway, and Unity cannot serialize properties so they won't appear in the inspector(Also private visibility fields are hidden from the inspector too, but i dunno the use-case for your fields).
Eg.:

```
public Color color{get; set;}
public bool active{get; set;}
public bool started{get; set;}
public PlayerAbilities playerAbilities{get; set;}
public PlayerMovement playerMovement{get; set;}
public PlayerControls controls{get; set;}
```

If you come from another programming language the above syntax might be strange for you, so you can read more about properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties).

Additionally, doing this:

```
[HideInInspector]
public bool boolean, anotherBoolean, andAnotherOne;
```

will apply the attribute tag for all the three fields.
But i don't really like this method because it often hurts readibility, unless you really group together variables that logically belongs together.

Answer (score -1):

ok it's actually very simple

I replaced the publics with protected

```
protected bool started;
protected Color color;
```

etc.

It's hidden in the inspector but i can access them.

Comment: Then you lost, visibility by doing that from now on only child classes will be able to see those fields, please refer to my answer, for more elegant, and robust solution

Comment: i mean you are right but i just wanted to access the fields in child classes